# How to invoke method with generic parameter type like SortedMap<Integer,Vector<double[]>>

Tags: java, generics, reflection, invoke

How do I invoke a method in an object where that method has a generic parameter of type `SortedMap<Integer,Vector<double[]>>`?

```
// "c" is actually a class of mine that extends Thread
Class<?> cls = Class.forName(c.getClass().getName());

Method meth = cls.getMethod("add", new Class[]{??????});  // What do I put here?

meth.invoke(c, allData);
```

Not sure what to put in the `new Class[]{}` array. I tried `SortedMap.class` but that won't work

Comment: How exactly "won't work" that? Do you mean that the `getMethod()` threw `NoSuchMethodException`?

Comment: yes, Errors out with NoSuchMethodException

Comment: Works for me and everyone else. By the way, why don't you just use `Class<?> cls = c.getClass();`?

Comment: Because I don't have a reference to the class only the name.  How did it work for you it errors out?  Did you write a test case?

Comment: If c extends Thread then cls is not a SortedMap and so c likely does not have add method? What object in your example is a SortedMap?

Comment: It makes no sense because `Class.forName(c.getClass().getName());` returns exactly the same as `c.getClass()`. I'd bet that it does not return the class you think it returns. Perhaps it returned `java.lang.Thread` instead of `com.example.YourClassExtendingThread`.

Comment: Unfortunately you guys are barking up the wrong tree the code works perfectly fine with my custom Thread classes.  I added a new method to them and it has a SortedMap parameter which is what I am trying to invoke.

Comment: @JPM - I've tried to get an answer from dp4j but I don't know of a method that expects SortedMap<Integer,Vector<double[]>> and Thread doesn't have it either. See if dp4j could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Class.getMethod()` uses varags these days. Have you tried

```
 Method meth = cls.getMethod("add", Map.class);
```

Comment: No because you get "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object"

Comment: SortedMap is an Interface you think I should use Map instead?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me :

```
public class MyClass {
```

```
public void test(ArrayList<String> p) {
    System.out.append("INVOKED !!");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    Class<?> klass = Class.forName("MyClass");

    Method m = klass.getMethod("test", ArrayList.class);
    m.invoke(myClass, new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

}

Comment: Uhhh that is an ArrayList not a SortedMap...but that gives me an idea.